# Fastest Way To Query SQL with Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I have an issue to looping SQL Query using VBA, its take a long time to run.
Total looping is 115 times in 15 minutes. Is there any way reduce the query time?
Here's is my code :

```
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    x = 1
    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=DWSQL\BCAPP;Database=TEST;Uid=admin;Pwd=admin;"
    Conn.Open sconnect
    Do
        If Sheets("Foil (+)").Cells(12, 12) <> "" And Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value Like "E*" Then
            sSqlSting = "SELECT *FROM [TEST].[dbo].[process_details] where pos_no = '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "' and scan_type = 'Anode Foil' and status = 'OK' and returned = 'N'"
        Else
            Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value = "E" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value
            sSqlSting = "SELECT *FROM [TEST].[dbo].[process_details] where pos_no = '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "' and scan_type = 'Anode Foil' and status = 'OK' and returned = 'N'"
        End If

        mrs.Open sSqlSting, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 18) = "" Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 18).CopyFromRecordset mrs
        Else
            Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset mrs
        End If
        mrs.Close
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) = ""
    Conn.Close
```

Comment: If the code works, you should post to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is for code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   sSqlSting = "SELECT *FROM [TEST].[dbo].[process_details] where scan_type = 'Anode Foil' and status = 'OK' and returned = 'N' and pos_no = in ('" 
enter code here

 Do
    If Sheets("Foil (+)").Cells(12, 12) <> "" And Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value Like "E*" Then
        sSqlSting = sSqlString &  Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "','"
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value = "E" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3).Value
        sSqlSting = sSqlString &  '" & Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) & "','"
    End If
     x = x + 1
Loop Until Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) = ""

 sSqlSting = left(sSqlSting,len(sSqlsting)-1) & ")"


    mrs.Open sSqlSting, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly
    If Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 18) = "" Then
        Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 18).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset mrs
    End If
    mrs.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...

Since your code works, and there isn't a lot you can do to speed up the actual processing of data within the worksheet (115 iterations is nothing), my guess is the bulk of the time is spent communicating with the database.

On that note, 15 minutes for 115 loops is extraordinary.

If you haven't already, make sure you have an index on:

```
scan_type, status, returned, pos_no
```

I'd recommend this all as a single index.

This is a band-aid.  You are doing 115 scans of the same table, and this only makes each scan more efficient -- it's like making 115 trips to the grocery store for 115 items and driving car instead of walking.

Parameterize your query.  Instead of passing literals, set up a parameter and send that with each loop.

This is also a band-aid and has more to do with decorum than performance, although there will be a performance impact, as you are compiling a statement once and executing it 115 times rather than compiling and executing 115 times.

Better yet, do a single scan of the table.  Execute your query one time, store the results in a data structure (a Dictionary object might do nicely) and then loop and apply those results.

If the results of this:

```
scan_type = 'Anode Foil' and status = 'OK' and returned = 'N'
```

Are sufficiently small (< 5000 or so records), I'd just run that up front and store it in a Dictionary, then loop through your spreadsheet.

If it's really large, then scan the spreadsheet first, run the query against just those 115 items, and then loop through the spreadsheet a second time to assign the values.  Passing an in-list as a parameter probably isn't possible (it is in PostgreSQL by the way), so your dynamic SQL approach is probably sufficient.

If you reach a point where you have thousands of items in the list, the best approach would be to load these into a temp table and then do a join against the table.